# Error de sintaxis Mysql en aplicacion Web J2EE Servlets y JSP's

Tags: mysql, sql, java-ee, jdbc

Estoy construyendo una pequeña app web usando NetBeans 8.2 con J2EE.

Al momento de ejecutar la siguiente consulta en el DAO, me muestra un error de sintaxis de MySQL que no existe ya que si ejecuto la consulta en el gestor de BD no hay ningún problema de sintaxis y la query se ejecuta sin problemas. A continuación mi código:

```
public Registro consultar(String placa) throws SQLException {
    String consulta = "select registro.id_registro, registro.horaInicio, registro.horaFin, registro.valorApagar, registro.id_cliente, registro.id_espacio, registro.placa, registro.tipo from registro inner join vehiculo on (registro.placa=vehiculo.placa) where vehiculo.placa=?;";
    PreparedStatement statement = this.conexion.prepareStatement(consulta);

    statement.setString(1, placa);

    ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery(consulta);

    while (resultado.next()) {
        TipoEspacio tipoEspacio = new TipoEspacio();
        tipoEspacio.setTipoEspacio(resultado.getString("id_espacio"));

        Espacio e = new Espacio();
        e.setNumeroEspacio(resultado.getInt("id_espacio"));
        e.setTipo(tipoEspacio);

        TipoVehiculo tipoVehiculo = new TipoVehiculo();
        tipoVehiculo.setTipo(resultado.getString("tipo"));
        Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();
        vehiculo.setPlaca(placa);
        vehiculo.setTipoVehiculo(tipoVehiculo);

        Registro registro = new Registro();
        registro.setEspacio(e);
        registro.setVehiculo(vehiculo);
        java.util.Date horaFin = new java.util.Date();
        registro.setHoraFin(horaFin);
        return registro;

    }
    return null;
}
```

El error que muestra Glassfish:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Intenta quitando el `;` final en tu consulta

Comment: Hola Pablo, gracias por tu respuesta.

No, acabo de intentarlo quitando el ";" y me sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error es porque estás llamando a `executeQuery` con un parámetro que no es necesario. Llámalo sin parámetros:

```
ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Muy buena vista, [`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--) no necesita la consulta, ya se le pasó antes.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh! Ese era el error.